# Why are the colors correct but not the labels in the legend on Dojo StackedColumn

Tags: dojo, xpages

I have an issue with the Legend on a StackedColumn chart. I have set the following dataSeries and legend elements.

[image]

In the code, I have the following for loop to assign all the labels to the values so that they appear in the legend.

```
v = compositeData.dataSeries;
y = compositeData.legend;
for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    dataSeries = v[i];
    r += '  ynchart.addSeries("'+y[i]+'", ['+dataSeries+']);'+@NewLine();
}
```

When I run the code, I end up with

[image]

showing the legend except the order of the labels is not in the order I expected. Element  [3] is first, followed by [0], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sShvX.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXBco.png). The color of the elements in the legend are in the correct order but somehow the label is not. I have no code in the script anywhere else that sorts anything. Why is the order of the legend label reordering itself and how do I fix it?

Comment: did you check source of those params?

Comment: Those legend params are from the Property Definition of the Custom Control. I created that and what you see is that they are in the proper order in the control. They match the dataSeries, which is in the proper order on the chart, but once the legend is displayed on the chart, the legend titles are out of order. The code is what it is and I cannot figure out how they got out of order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify a parameter in a custom control as "multi-instance" you hand over a java.util.List. The List doesn't guarantee you any delivery sequence and that seems what is happening here. So you are probably better of handing over ONE parameter which you then split(). Of course that leans itself to the potential issue that your label and values get out of sync. So you might want to hand over a complete JSON with all included as parameter. Something like:

```
{ "values" : { "worldwide" : [10,20,30],
               "NA" : [2,10,20],
               "Europe" : [4,5,4],
               "Japan" : [4,5,6]
             }
}
```

You could consider a function that you hand the names of your fields that returns that string for you.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that the java.util.List would scramble the order of the elements. Now I have to figure out how to re-engineer this part of the system and keep the rest of it working at the same time.